# How to generate ssh key with AES-GCM?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I used that form to create my ssh key : `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"` and I got: Encryption: aes256-cbc, is it possible to use aes256-gcm@openssh.com instead?
thanks

Comment: This looks like a XY problem, why do you want that specific cipher?

Comment: @Nicolas Formichella
 it is supposed to be better than cbc

Comment: @NicolasFormichella because it defeats Terrapin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`man 1 ssh-keygen`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html) states :

```
 -Z cipher
         Specifies the cipher to use for encryption when writing an
         OpenSSH-format private key file.  The list of available
         ciphers may be obtained using "ssh -Q cipher".  The default
         is “aes256-ctr”.
```

---

```bash
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -Z "aes256-gcm@openssh.com" -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Should work just fine